# Change from hourly price to daily price

Tags: invoice

I do not know where, but the following code is always billing price per hour and sometimes I get paid per day, not per hour, is there a way to change this?

Here is the link to the repository:
https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/latex-rechnung I'm using.

And does someone have a solution for, when I get paid for one day of work, but need to work extra hours and would like to bill them.

```
% koma_env.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[german]{invoice}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% include meta data
\include{_data}
% ################## invoice DATA ##################
\newcommand{\invoiceDate}{\today} % Datum der rechnungsstellung, change `\today' to a different  date, if you do not want to use todays date
\newcommand{\payDate}{DD.MM.YYYY} % Datum der Zahlungsfrist
\newcommand{\invoiceReference}{YYYYMMDD-1} % Rechnungsnummer (z.B. 20150122-4)
\newcommand{\invoiceSalutation}{} % die Anrede
\newcommand{\invoiceText}{Folgende Positionen werden in Rechnung gestellt:} % Rechnungstext
\newcommand{\invoiceEnclosures}{} % \encl{} einfügen
\newcommand{\invoiceClosing}{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
% ################## invoice DATA ##################

% ################## Customer DATA ##################
\newcommand{\customerCompany}{Firma XYZ} %ggf. Firma
\newcommand{\customerName}{Max Mustermann} % Name
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Robert-Koch-Str. 12} % Straße
\newcommand{\customerZIP}{12345} % Postleitzahl
\newcommand{\customerCity}{Musterstadt} % Ort
% ################## Customer DATA ##################

\setkomavar{fromname}{\senderName}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\senderStreet \\ \senderZIP \ \senderCity}
\setkomavar{place}{\senderCity}
\setkomavar{date}{\invoiceDate}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{\senderTelephone}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{\senderMobilephone}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{\href{mailto:\senderEmail}{\nolinkurl{\senderEmail}}}
\setkomavar{subject}{Rechnung}
\setkomavar{location}{
  \\[\baselineskip] \\[\baselineskip]
  \flushright \small {\vspace{1cm}Rechnungsnummer: 
  \invoiceReference}
}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill
   \parbox[t][\headheight][t]{7.2cm}{% <================================== 6cm
   \footnotesize
   \raggedright
   \flushright
   \color[gray]{.3}%
\begin{tabular}{rl}
     Anschrift & \usekomavar{fromname}\\
     & \senderStreet\\
     & \senderZIP  \ \senderCity \\
     \\
     %\Telefon \ Telefon:  \` \senderTelephone \\
     Mobil  & \usekomavar{frommobilephone} \\
     E-Mail  & \usekomavar{fromemail} \\
     Webseite & {\normalfont\ttfamily  \senderWeb } \\
     \\
     Steuernummer & \taxID \\
     \\
     Institut & \accountBankName \\
     IBAN & \accountIBAN \\
     BIC & \accountBIC
\end{tabular}                   
   }%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{\customerCompany \\ \customerName \\ 
\customerStreet \\ \customerZIP \ \customerCity}

        \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{logo.png}            
        \opening{\invoiceSalutation}
        \invoiceText
        \begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}


\ProjectTitle{Projekttitel} % <=========================================
\Fee{Musterdienstleistung 1}{30.00}{4}
\Fee{Musterdienstleistung 2}{36.00}{7}

% Auslagen
%\EBCi{Hotel, 12 Nächte} {2400.00}
%\STExpenses

% Rabatt
\Discount{Rabatt} {20} % <==============================================
        \end{invoice}
    \ps Im ausgewiesenen Betrag ist gemäß § 19 UStG keine Umsatzsteuer 
    enthalten.

    \closing{\invoiceClosing}
    \invoiceEnclosures



    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to expand the style `invoice` in the preamble of your document with the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\UnitDay            {Preis/Tag}% <========================================

\newcommand{\FeeDay@Title}{% <==========================================
    \\
    \noindent\textbf{\Activity}&&\UnitDay&\Count&\Amount\ (\BC)\\
    \hline%
}%

\newcommand{\FeeDay}[3]{% Yields state 3, Print Fee Item <==============
    %
    % #1 Contents
    % #2 Fee per Day
    % #3 Unit Count
    %
    \ifcase\Flag % 0: Invoice not started yet
        \error@message{\MissingOpening}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 1: Start invoice
        %
        \error@message{\MissingProject}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 2: Start project, print title
        %
        \FeeDay@Title%
        \Fee@Line{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 3: Print remuneration item
        %
        \Fee@Line{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 4: Print subtotal remuneration
        %
        \warning@message{\FeeSTExists}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 5: Expense item
        %
        \error@message{\FeeBeforeExpense}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 6: Print subtotal expenses
        %
        \error@message{\FeeBeforeExpense}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 7: Print subtotal project
        %
        \error@message{\ProjectCompletedNoFee}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 8: Print total, close invoice
        %
        \error@message{\InvoiceCompletedNoFee}%
        %
        %
    \else \error@message{\InternalError}%
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother
```

Please see that you have to define new commnands `\def\UnitDay` (I did only for german!), `\FeeDay@Title` to print the heading with "Preis/Tag" and `\FeeDay` to print one calculation for one work done at x days.

So you can use this commands in this way:

```
\ProjectTitle{Tagesleistungen} % <=========================================
\FeeDay{Musterdienstleistung 3}{360.00}{3}
```

In the following MWE I keept the old invoice and added the new commands and code I showed above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[german]{invoice}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\UnitDay            {Preis/Tag}% <========================================

\newcommand{\FeeDay@Title}{% <==========================================
    \\
    \noindent\textbf{\Activity}&&\UnitDay&\Count&\Amount\ (\BC)\\
    \hline%
}%

\newcommand{\FeeDay}[3]{% Yields state 3, Print Fee Item <==============
    %
    % #1 Contents
    % #2 Fee per Day
    % #3 Unit Count
    %
    \ifcase\Flag % 0: Invoice not started yet
        \error@message{\MissingOpening}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 1: Start invoice
        %
        \error@message{\MissingProject}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 2: Start project, print title
        %
        \FeeDay@Title%
        \Fee@Line{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 3: Print remuneration item
        %
        \Fee@Line{#1}{#2}{#3}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 4: Print subtotal remuneration
        %
        \warning@message{\FeeSTExists}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 5: Expense item
        %
        \error@message{\FeeBeforeExpense}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 6: Print subtotal expenses
        %
        \error@message{\FeeBeforeExpense}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 7: Print subtotal project
        %
        \error@message{\ProjectCompletedNoFee}%
        %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \or % 8: Print total, close invoice
        %
        \error@message{\InvoiceCompletedNoFee}%
        %
        %
    \else \error@message{\InternalError}%
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% include meta data
\include{_data} % <============== delete in this file the following data!
% ################## invoice DATA ##################
\newcommand{\invoiceDate}{DD.MM.YYYY} % Datum der rechnungsstellung
\newcommand{\payDate}{DD.MM.YYYY} % Datum der Zahlungsfrist
\newcommand{\invoiceReference}{YYYYMMDD-1} % Rechnungsnummer (z.B. 20150122-4)
\newcommand{\invoiceSalutation}{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,} % die Anrede
\newcommand{\invoiceText}{Für die von mir erbrachte Leistung erhalten sie
hiermit die Rechnung. Bitte zahlen Sie den unten aufgeführten Gesamtbetrag
unter Angabe der Rechnungsnummer (\invoiceReference) bis
zum \payDate \ auf das angegebene Konto ein.} % Rechnungstext
\newcommand{\invoiceEnclosures}{} % \encl{} einfügen
\newcommand{\invoiceClosing}{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}
% ################## invoice DATA ##################

% ################## Customer DATA ##################
\newcommand{\customerCompany}{Firma XYZ} %ggf. Firma
\newcommand{\customerName}{Max Mustermann} % Name
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Robert-Koch-Str. 12} % Straße
\newcommand{\customerZIP}{12345} % Postleitzahl
\newcommand{\customerCity}{Musterstadt} % Ort
% ################## Customer DATA ##################

\setkomavar{fromname}{\senderName}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\senderStreet \\ \senderZIP \ \senderCity}
\setkomavar{place}{\senderCity}
\setkomavar{date}{\invoiceDate}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{\senderTelephone}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{\senderMobilephone}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{\href{mailto:\senderEmail}{\nolinkurl{\senderEmail}}}
\setkomavar{subject}{Rechnung}
\setkomavar{location}{
  \\[\baselineskip] \\[\baselineskip]
  \flushright \small {\vspace{1cm}Rechnungsnummer: 
  \invoiceReference}
}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill
   \parbox[t][\headheight][t]{7cm}{% <================================== 6cm
   \footnotesize
   \raggedright
   \flushright
   \color[gray]{.3}%
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
         Anschrift & \usekomavar{fromname}\\
         & \senderStreet\\
         & \senderZIP  \ \senderCity \\
         \\
         %\Telefon \ Telefon:  \` \senderTelephone \\
         Mobil  & \usekomavar{frommobilephone} \\
         E-Mail  & \usekomavar{fromemail} \\
         Webseite & {\normalfont\ttfamily  \senderWeb } \\
         \\
         Steuernummer & \taxID \\
         \\
         Institut & \accountBankName \\
         IBAN & \accountIBAN \\
         BIC & \accountBIC
    \end{tabular}                   
   }%
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{\customerCompany \\ \customerName \\ 
    \customerStreet \\ \customerZIP \ \customerCity}

            \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{logo.png}            
            \opening{\invoiceSalutation}
            \invoiceText
            \begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
\ProjectTitle{Projekttitel} % <=========================================
\Fee{Musterdienstleistung 1}{30.00}{4}
\Fee{Musterdienstleistung 2}{36.00}{7}
\ProjectTitle{Tagesleistungen} % <=========================================
\FeeDay{Musterdienstleistung 3}{360.00}{3}

% Auslagen
%\EBC{Hotel, 12 Nächte} {2400.00} % \EBCi{Hotel, 12 Nächte} {2400.00}
%\STExpenses

% Rabatt
\Discount{Rabatt} {20} % <==============================================
            \end{invoice}
        \ps Im ausgewiesenen Betrag ist gemäß § 19 UStG keine Umsatzsteuer 
        enthalten.

        \closing{\invoiceClosing}
        \invoiceEnclosures



    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: A good answer addressing the original questions. However I note the rebate is applied as simple fixed discount of -20.00 Whereas I would normally in this type of case expect it to alternately be available as say 5% is there an(other) variable (did I miss one) that can be addressed to expand that functionality ?